# Tabs JQuery UI: not show graphic elements in inactive tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tabs

I have this problem: I've implemented a tab function with JQuery UI Tabs, where in the first one contains texts elements (active) and in the second one contains graphics elements. This is my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active" ><a href="#element1-text" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#element2-graphics" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="#element1-text">
   <!-- Here implement text -->
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="#element2-graphics">
   <!-- Here implement graphics -->
</div>
```

When I pressed the "#element2-graphics" tab my graphics (map and charts) shown incomplete, but when I resize the explorer these show perfectly. I've implemented to refresh and load methods of this tabs, and I spent a lot of hours to resolve this. Anyone have idea of this bug?